# Facebook Graph API limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have researched and I am on the conclusion that Facebook Graph API limits are ***600 requests per 600 sec per access token***.

And since I am using the new Graph API only, I have never encounter the need of passing an access token manually. I believe one needs to pass on with the old REST API. It should mean that with every different user of my app, I have a different access token and my API limit for the next 600 secs is reset. Can anyone confirm?

What if I am using **offline_access** permission? I read somewhere that with offline_access permission the access token never changes and hence you can access data any time. True? Then in this case I just have the rate of 600 requests / 600 sec for this access token. Correct?

I am building an app that I believe will go viral, so I am trying not to be blocked out of my API usage. On a visit (it totally works on AJAX), I use 10-15 queries per user, so considering the rate, I am much below the rate at which I can use FB API?

So as a whole, I may have a million users for my app, letting me to do 600 requests / 600 sec for each user's access token, all simultaneously.

Can anyone please comment?

Comment: Ok! I found out that I will need to pass access token manually when I want to authenticate my application and work with data without any user.

Comment: Glad you figured things out! As a side note; however, you may want to take into account that Facebook will soon be deprecating the **offline access** permission. You can read more about the new endpoint and how to build your application with 60-day access tokens [here](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/).

Comment: Yes, I am very well aware of that but I am not developing any FB apps these days. Thanks! :)

Comment: Whoops! I guess I forgot to check when this was posted! haha

Comment: No worries! Will help someone coming here for sure :)

Comment: @RobertGreathouse The day I launched it, FB broke their JS SDK compatibility with PHP SDK, and wasn't fixed for more than a month, so never got around to actually launch the app. Just considered it to be as a learning phase.

Answer (score 4):

API rate limits are primarily based on the number of users using the application.  So as your app's popularity increases the total number of API calls you can make also increases. Under normal usage rate limits should not be an issue.  Focus on being efficient on a per-user basis.

Note: offline_access is being deprecated - but it is easy to refresh user tokens:
https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. Just wanted someone to confirm the high limits FB let us have.

Answer (score 1):

> Each app is given an allotment of 200 API calls per user in any given 60 minute window.

Quoted from : https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/33103876 
Documentation : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting