# Prevent Facebook to freeze account during SDK testing?

Tags: android, facebook

I implemented a small Facebook app via its SDK.

I was testing posting message to my wall extensively and today I saw that Facebook has frozen my account for 1 month.

I am now opening another FB test account.

How can I prevent them to freeze this one again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to not exceed the Facebook API call limits. Taken from the [Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#policies):

> If you exceed, or plan to exceed, any of the following thresholds please contact [Facebook] as you may be subject to additional terms: (>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day).

See also this question: [What's the Facebook's Graph API call limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713241/whats-the-facebooks-graph-api-call-limit)

Comment: I suspect OP isn't using Test Users correctly: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/