# Facebook Graph API - Maximum number of requests

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building a Facebook app for my Master thesis. Currently I am testing the app and everything works. I just checked the statistics on Insight and saw that with 11 users I have already done 40K requests. I am about to start the survey and this concerns me a little bit, does Facebook has a maximum number of requests for the application in total? I have found that there is a 600 requests per 600 secends per user, but not for the app in total.

Thank you in advance,

M

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713241/whats-the-facebooks-graph-api-call-limit, there seem to be *some*, but noone seems to have specific numbers.