# Best way to cache Open Graph results from Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, caching, curl, facebook-opengraph

My site queries Facebook for a share count via cURL:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=MY_SITE_URL
```

However, I frequently find that I've reached the [rate limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713241/whats-the-facebooks-graph-api-call-limit).  What's the best mechanism to cache this data and display it on the page?  My site does not use a database, and it seems silly to create one just for this purpose.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes memcache or Redis is a good option.

Other way is you can use batch API functionality of Facebook. It will do multiple request at once as a result in one query you could found share count of more that one URL.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/

Second option is you can create global array in php. for e.g

```
$globalArray = array();
```

You can then create key for every Share Count URL and then store the result that you get it from the API. for e.g.

```
$globalArray['url'] = $resultFromAPI;
```

By that way you could store the data until you refresh the page.

Third option is create session of every share count URL and store the value in it and clear the session when user is log-out.

Then every time when you fetch share count for particular URL first check that you have a value for that URL or not ? for e.g

```
if(isset($_SESSION['url']) && !empty($_SESSION['url']){
    $count = $_SESSION['url'];    
}else{
    // fetch through facebook graph API
}
```

If you are using Zend Framework than Zend Registry is also a good option it will work same like PHP sessions.

If you want up to date information than you need call Graph API. But you could built logic that fetch data after one hour only.I mean you could clear the session every one hour for those Share URLs and save data in to those session variables again.

Hope it Helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add an app access token to your request. This should ideally solve your rate limit problems. Give it a try:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=MY_SITE_URL&access_token={app_id}|{app_secret}
```

You could for example use Redis as a cache and EXPIRE 3600 the keys (in this case maybe a md5 hash of the URL) containing the Graph API result data to cache the data for one hour...

See

- http://redis.io
- http://redis.io/commands/expire
- https://github.com/nrk/predis

Comment: Users don't log into my website, which seems like a requirement for this solution.  Is that correct?

Comment: An app access token is not related to user access tokens, which are gathered upon using Facebook Login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens I wonder: Is the call to the Graph API made upon every request that hits you site? If so, that would be baaaad design.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid.  I want to get reasonably up-to-date information for ever user, and I'm wondering how to cache it so it doesn't make a request on every page hit.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be, you can create temporary file with name of file as the hash of the url by converting the url to hash and based on timestamp of the file work with the refreshing of cache or deleting expired cache.

```
//Pseudo Code
urlHash = Hash(url)

if urlHash path exists:
   if check_valid_timestamp:
      fetch_file()
endif

if dont have data:
   get_data_from_url()
   create_and_store_in_file()
endif

show_result()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use memcache or redis for the same. Caching each user data along with other details as per requirement. You can use the individual ids or urls as cache key for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a master or a high level programmer. I had a similar problem once, even though not with facebook.

So what I did was like, I maintained a file in the server where I stored a timestamp and the current count.[I believe you can create files in your server.] And when each request came, I checked the current timestamp with the timestamp in  the file. So if the difference was more than 30 minutes[you can set your limit arbitrarily] I would send the API request once more and update the file with new timestamp and count. On the contrary, if the difference was less than 30 minutes what I did was take the count in the file and display it rather than sending the  API request.

This is a very simple and efficient way. But I don't know if this is what you are looking for and it will solve your problem.