# Can we periodically call Facebook Graph Api?

Tags: ios, facebook

We would like to periodically as for period you can imagine every 10 or 15 minutes or every hour, grt data from Facebook graph Api. I know we have to autenticate with Fb app token, but can we do it so? Wont the app be banned by Facebook if it crawls data every 15 minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no exact limits for API calls. In general, they say "600 calls per 600 seconds, per token & per IP". If you do one call every 10-15min it will definitely be no problem at all. But it may be a problem if you try to get the whole feed of a Page every 10-15min, for example. Because you can´t get all entries in one call and you have to use [paging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#paging).

More information: [What's the Facebook's Graph API call limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713241/whats-the-facebooks-graph-api-call-limit)

About Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/