# Facebook Marketing API Rate Limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I know that fb have made available some documentation about the requests limits to the api https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/api-rate-limiting, 
but it is not clear how each api call is calculated...

i.e, If I want to get stats for ~10,000 adsets, how can I evenly space the time between the calls ?

Comment: To resolve this issue you should apply for Standard Access Level. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access

Comment: Hi Amit, can you specify, if your question was about Graph API or Marketing API? The question suggests that it is about Marketing API, but the answer you have accepted is answering the issue for Graph API. Do you remember?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best answer i could find for this question from another SO thread -

> "After some testing and discussion with the Facebook platform team, there is no official limit I'm aware of or can find in the documentation. However, I've found **600 calls per 600 seconds, per token & per IP** to be about where they stop you. I've also seen some application based rate limiting but don't have any numbers.
>
> As a general rule, **one call per second should not get rate limited**. On the surface this seems very restrictive but remember you can batch certain calls and use the subscription API to get changes."

Source - [What's the Facebook's Graph API call limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713241/whats-the-facebooks-graph-api-call-limit)

Official Doc-: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting

Answer (score 2):

Rate limits are imposed on each app. The rate limiting tool gives you information about how close your app is to being throttled. Click on any sample to get more detail on the types of utilization.

Your app can make 200 calls per hour per user in aggregate. As an example, if your app has 100 users, this means that your app can make 20,000 calls. This isn't a per-user limit, so one user could make 19,000 of those calls and another could make 1,000. This limit is calculated based on the number of calls made in the previous hour.

Source-: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting

Heavily rate-limited per ad account. For development only. Not for production apps running for live advertisers.