# Facebook Lead Ads read limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

IS there any limit to calling Lead ads  read API? There is no clear documentation on Reading Lead Ads limit in facebook

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Marketing API Rate Limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472887/facebook-marketing-api-rate-limit)

Answer (score 0):

There is rate limit for Marketing API. Reading lead data belongs to it.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/api-rate-limiting