# Maximum limit fetching facebook pages with Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

What is the maximum limit for fetching the facebook pages from an account?

Let's suppose if a facebook account has more than 200 pages to administer. If I try to retrieve facebook pages of that account using `'/me/accounts'` edge.

Then I get `data` as well as `paging` (containing `cursors` and `next`, `previous` page links). What I want to know is If I can set a limit while fetching the facebook pages like `'/me/accounts?limit=200'` and get all the 200 facebook pages the account has??

I have searched the documentation But there is no clear explanation as for this `rate limit`.

Comment: Just wondering, I'm tracking data for a customer. For getting likes of a post I can go up to `limit=500`.  If a post has 1000 likes, using the default limit of 25 it would take 40 calls instead of only 2. If I assume a safe limit of 200 calls per hour per user without triggering the rate limit exceed error, the default limit would reach this number very quickly per hour.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean the API limit, it´s dynamic and not a definitive value. A general rule is "600 calls per 600 seconds, per token & per IP". You can also read this in other Stackoverflow threads, for example: [What's the Facebook's Graph API call limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713241/whats-the-facebooks-graph-api-call-limit)

If you mean the limit parameter: Afaik they are changing it from time to time. I would not rely on it and just use the default value with paging, which is usually 25.

Comment: How can I specify the limit (increase it) using the facebook python sdk?

Comment: it is just a parameter, like "limit=100", in the api call.

Comment: Thanks! I've realized that using the python SDK it should be passed to the get_insights method of the async_call object when asking for the results, and not in the original async call params.