# For loop printing String only once when the condition is equal to 25

Tags: android, json, for-loop, facebook-graph-api, jsonexception

I'm trying to print out an object in the `JSON` using Facebook Graph API.

Here's my code:

```
try{
    JSONArray data = innerJson.getJSONArray("data");
    Log.d("innerDataLength", String.valueOf(data.length()));

    for (int i = 0; i<data.length(); i++) {
        String message = data.getJSONObject(i).getString("message");
        Log.d("message", message);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.d("exception", e.getMessage());
}
```

Here's output:

```
D/innerDataLength: 25
D/message: "blah blah blah"
D/exception: No value for message
```

As you can see the `condition` i.e. `data.length()` is 25 then why am I getting the message printed out only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you get an exception:

> D/exception: No value for message

It indicates that the second object in `JSONArray` has no `message` property. Looks like it's optional, so you need to check whether `message` property exists first.

Update:

```
try{
    JSONArray data = innerJson.getJSONArray("data");
    Log.d("innerDataLength", String.valueOf(data.length()));

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = data.getJSONObject(i);
        if (obj.has("message")) {
            String message = obj.getString("message");
            Log.d("message", message);
        }
        if (obj.has("story")) {
            String story= obj.getString("story");
            Log.d("story", story);
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.d("exception", e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: the second one has a `story` property. Can you please give me the code to get both `message` and `story`?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the code, Olexiy. The limit is of just 25 here.. how can I get all the posts?

Comment: Try to add `limit` parameter to your URL as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29730526/maximum-limit-fetching-facebook-pages-with-graph-api

Comment: there's something called paging where we gets `previous` and `next` graph's link.. do you know how to access that for going through all the pages?

Comment: Create a loop that first sends an original Facebook Graph API request, and then if response contains "next" property, repeat request with URL specified in that property.

Answer (score 0):

some of object in innerJson.getJSONArray("data") array don't has message

to check what i say comment the line inside loop and just print i will get 0 to 24

to avoid that surrounded the statment of parsing message with try and catch to avoid parsing object that not contain message

you can also print data.getJSONObject(i).toString to see parsing object