# Detect exceeded limit of ad creation in Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I have to create number of ads per one loop interation. For example I have pre-set 100 campaigns on my backend and then by one click I want to create ads. During one iteration I create one AdSet, one AdCreative, one AdImage and finally one Ad. So the maximum of ads I can create is 2 ads per 5 minute (then it throwing error that limit is over for Ad creation). It's terrible. I want to see why it's so limited, but cannot find any chance too see exceeded limit. I am using PHP Facebook Marketing API SDK ver. 2.6 
Hope there are some developers how know about it.

Error code:

```
Array ( 
[code] => 613 
[error_subcode] => 1487742 
[message] => Calls to this api have exceeded the rate limit. 
[error_user_title] => There have been too many calls from this ad-account. Wait a bit and try again. 
[error_user_msg] => There have been too many calls from this ad-account. Wait a bit and try again. 
[error_blame_field_specs] => [type] => OAuthException )
```

Answer (score 1):

Marketing API has it is own rate limiting logic and is excluded from all the graph api rate limitations.

You can check Marketing API Rate Limiting [Marketing API Rate Limiting](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/api-rate-limiting)

Also Limit of ads creation or API Rate Limiting depends on your Marketing API Access Levels [Marketing API Access Levels](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access)

If you have higher access level (i.e Standard) then your API Rate Limiting will be higher

Comment: Yes, you are right.I covered all these materials before to post the question. Anyway, I don't understand how to detect limit for Ad creation (the error throwing only during Ad creation). Look at my case please: 1. I have one ad account 2. The app is on public mode already, also I sent application for basic mode access 3. The maximum number of ads I can create is 2, only 2 then I got this error of exceeded rate limit

Comment: @Nadeem0025 any ideas how to get the number of api calls for ad creation? I also attached error code, maybe it would be helpful

Comment: @EugeneMescheryakov there is no way to get the number of api calls. While creation of ad you are sending many api calls and that's why getting error of exceeded rate limit. 

There should be some time difference between creating ads or  [Apply for Standard Access Levels](https://web.facebook.com/business/standardadsapi)  for avoiding that issue

Comment: Also check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713241/whats-the-facebooks-graph-api-call-limit